# Exclude numbers starting with a certain three digits in C#

Tags: c#

I am currently building a C# application that is generating a random 9 digit number each run through. I am looking for a way to exclude numbers starting with "666". How would I go about writing a statement to exclude numbers starting with certain digits.

Here's the code snippet just in case it helps.

```
Random SSN = new Random();
string temp = "";
int num = SSN.Next(100000000, 999999999);
temp = num.ToString();
```

Thanks!

Comment: Why isn't 999999999 included? Is that by design or a subtle bug?

Comment: That is actually by design. Well it was more for people looking at the code that didn't know C# than anything else, just so they can visualize it a little easier.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, you *could* write:

```
int num;
do {
   num = SSN.Next(100000000, 999999999);
} while (num >= 666000000 && num < 667000000);
```

(I originally used a string comparison too, but as we've always got exactly 9 digits, we can make a numeric comparison easily.)

Comment: +1 but [the real number is 616](http://www.religionnewsblog.com/11134/beasts-real-mark-devalued-to-616) :)

Answer (score 4):

The easy way would be:

```
Random SSN = new Random();
string temp = "";
do
{
    int num = SSN.Next(100000000, 999999999);
    temp = num.ToString();
} while (temp.StartsWith("666"));
```

If you’re really into efficiency and want to avoid the string comparison and unbounded loop at all costs, you could use:

```
Random SSN = new Random();
int num = SSN.Next(100000000, 998999999);
if (num >= 666000000)
    num += 1000000;
```

Comment: I would replace the call to the StartsWith function for (temp[0] == '6' && temp[1] == '6' && temp[2] == '6') as comparing fixed chars positions is a lot faster.

Comment: I like the efficient way... very nice.

Comment: @AdrianSalazar: The second version would be much faster than any improvement on the string-based version.

Comment: @Douglas yeah, naturally! I just commented in any case someone would opt to use the easiest, CPU killer version.

Comment: @AdrianSalazar: Fair enough; your observation on char comparisons being faster is valid.

Answer (score 2):

```
Random SSN = new Random();
string temp = "";
double d = 0.6; // This will help on of choosing one half

int n1 = SSN.Next(100000000, 666000000);
int n2 = SSN.Next(667000000, 999999999);

int num = SSN.NextDouble() > d ? n1 : n2; 

temp = num.ToString();
```

Comment: This will never generate 665999999 or 999999999

Comment: @PenchoIlchev True. I apologize for the 665999999, but the original snippet will also miss the 999999999. Anyways, looking into how this post is evolving, I might dare to say that precision (and CPU optimization) are something not so important for the problem.

Comment: yeah, you are right about 999999999. About the precision and the complexity: I think that this is what makes the problem more interesting :)

Answer (score 0):

```
Random SSN = new Random();
string temp = "";
do
{
    int num = SSN.Next(100000000, 999999999);
    temp = num.ToString();
} while(num.IndexOf("666") == 0);
```

Comment: Pretty sure you want `StartsWith`, not `IndexOf`.

Answer (score 0):

This has complexity of O(1).

```
                string temp = "";
                if (SSN.Next(0,999999999) < 588339221)
                {
                    temp = SSN.Next(100000000, 666000000).ToString();
                }
                else
                {
                    temp = SSN.Next(667000000, 1000000000).ToString();
                }
```

Comment: That's now biased towards values greater than 666999999.

Comment: You could kind of fix it (not very accurate) by using `SSN.NextDouble() < 0.629588432` I suppose, but why do it the hard way?

Comment: @harold Because this is O(1) rather than O(infinity).  If the ranges were variable (and therefore the "bad" region was potentially larger) it could be a more significant issue.

Comment: Thanks, Fixed it, although it will still skew the distribution a bit as the ratio between the ranges is 0.58833922188752512700976170849781 rather than 0.6